# How to detect if an element is outside of its container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

So I've created the the following [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-eeesb). I got a webapp that relies heavily on user input. For demonstration purposes I've kept it simple by displaying a bunch of authors on a a4 formatted page. The `page` and `font-size` both use `vw` unit to make it responsive.

As you can see in the codesandbox, the last few authors are forced off the page because it no longer fits inside the container. Ideally I'd like to detect the content that doesn't fit on the page anymore, and generate a second identical a4 page to display that particular content.

Currently in my webapp I've just added `overflow: scroll;` to the page `div` where all the content is placed in, so that it at least looks somewhat 'ok'. But it isn't a very good User Experience and I'd like to improve it.

I don't have a clue where to start so any help in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

### CSS

```
#app {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font: 12pt "Tahoma";
}

.book {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  font: 3vw "Tahoma";
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  /* overflow: scroll; */
  display: block;
  width: calc(100 / 23 * 21vw);
  height: calc(100 / 23 * 29.7vw);
  margin: calc(100 / 23 * 1vw) auto;
  border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.subpage {
  margin: calc(100 / 23 * 1vw);
  width: calc(100 / 23 * 19vw);
  height: calc(100 / 23 * 27.7vw);
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: 0cm #FAFAFA solid;
}

.subpage-content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

### Javascript

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      authors: [
        { id: 1, name: "Smith" },
        { id: 2, name: "Johnson" },
        { id: 3, name: "Williams" },
        { id: 4, name: "Jones" },
        { id: 5, name: "Brown" },
        { id: 6, name: "Davis" },
        { id: 7, name: "Miller" },
        { id: 8, name: "Wilson" },
        { id: 9, name: "Moore" },
        { id: 10, name: "Taylor" },
        { id: 11, name: "Anderson" },
        { id: 12, name: "Thomas" },
        { id: 13, name: "Jackson" },
        { id: 14, name: "White" },
        { id: 15, name: "Harris" },
        { id: 16, name: "Martin" },
        { id: 17, name: "Thomspson" },
        { id: 18, name: "Garcia" },
        { id: 19, name: "Martinez" },
        { id: 20, name: "Robinson" },
        { id: 21, name: "Clark" },
        { id: 22, name: "Rodeiquez" },
        { id: 23, name: "Lewis" },
        { id: 24, name: "Lee" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
```

### HTML

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="book">
        <div class="page">HEADER
          <div class="subpage" id="editor-container">Authors:
            <!-- <div class="subpage-content">The real content</div> -->
            <div v-for="item in authors" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Normally, using vw is not great for responsiveness. I would recommend looking into flexbox and/or breakpoints

Comment: Is the visual frame of the page only there for visualising to the user how content fits within the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view a [fork of your code sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-6t7uv).

I changed the data structure (and template) to have a `pages` array in which each page has an `authors` array, instead of a single one. Initially, the first page holds all the authors.

```js
data() {
  return {
    pages: [
      {
        authors: [
          { id: 1, name: "Smith" },
          ...
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page" v-for="(page, pageIndex) in pages" :key="pageIndex">HEADER
  <div class="subpage" id="editor-container">
    <template v-if="pageIndex < 1">Authors:</template>
    <!-- <div class="subpage-content">The real content</div> -->
    <div v-for="item in page.authors" :key="item.id" class="author">{{ item.name }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I then created a method `recalcPages` that gets called when the component is mounted:

```js
  methods: {
    recalcPages() {
      let pageElements = this.$el.querySelectorAll(".page");
      Array.from(pageElements).some((p, pi) => {
        let authors = p.querySelectorAll(".author");
        if (authors.length) {
          return Array.from(authors).some((a, ai) => {
            let offPage = a.offsetTop + a.offsetHeight > p.offsetHeight;
            if (offPage) {
              let currentAuthors = this.pages[pi].authors;
              var p1 = currentAuthors.slice(0, ai);
              var p2 = currentAuthors.slice(ai);

              this.pages[pi].authors = p1;
              this.pages.push({ authors: p2 });
            }
            return offPage;
          });
        }
        return false;
      });
    }
  },
```

It iterates the actual DOM nodes and uses `offsetTop` + `offsetHeight` to calculate whether an author is off the page or not. As soon as an element leaves the page, it and all following elements are split from the current page's `authors` and a second page is inserted.

You'll also need to call `this.recalcPages()` after updating the contents deleting all pages and set a new `authors` array on the first one to be split up automatically again, unless you're only adding to the last page. You could also try to use the `updated` hook to achieve this automatically, I haven't tried that.

Of course it's quite a heavy operation, as it renders the component just to trigger re-rendering again by modifying the data. But unless you don't know the exact height of every element, there's no way around it (at least none I'm aware of).

By the way (although your final data will probably look different, but just for the sake of completeness of this demonstration) I also wrapped your `Authors:` headline in `<template v-if="pageIndex < 1">Authors:</template>` in order to display it only on the first page.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very clear demonstration and approach to the problem. Will try to implement this today on my website. Thanks again for taking the time :).

Comment: Hi Constantin, just shy of a year later and I came back to this question since I again need this (in a slightly different form). You said something that I would like your opinion on. You said: `But unless you don't know the exact height of every element, there's no way around it (at least none I'm aware of).`. What would change about the answer if you did know the exact height of every element?

Comment: If all elements had the same height, you wouldn't need to re-calculatte the offset values again and again. You could just calculate how many elements fit into one page and then split the authors into pages accordingly.